# Breaking changes in windows update 1903 for outlook office JS based add-in

Tags: office-js, microsoft-edge, windows-update

We noticed few breaking changes after installing latest windows update with regards to office JS based add-ins.

1. The add-in host browser is changed from IE to edge.
2. There are breaking changes with links, previously inside add-in if you have an anchor tag with target="_blank" it used to open in a new browser window. Now its opening inside a new window with in Office browser(same as dialogApi dialog) if domain on target page is same domain as add-in domain.
3. From the dialog we are not able to open new page, all links to other domain fails.

I could not see any information about introducing the new browser in the release notes for Update [1903](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1903#microsoft-edge).

Is there a way to make the links open in a new browser window(as before upgrading to 1903) regardless of domain?

Comment: Which client are you using? Are you using the desktop Outlook client on Windows? Also, for question 2, are you saying that the links in the add-in window open up in the underlying hosts browser instead of your default system browser?

Comment: I am using native outlook Version 1906(Build 11727.20224). And the links from the add-in window open up in the underlying host browser instead of the default system browser if the link domain is same as add-in domain. If the domain is different it opens in the system default browser.

Answer (score 0):

The new functionality of anchor tags is by design.

I am unable to reproduce the errors opening links to other domains in the dialog. What exactly is the error you're seeing?

Comment: The issue is previous windows version when outlook used to use IE to render the add-ins. The anchor tag always used to open in a new window regardless of the domain. But after the update when Edge is used to render the add-ins the functionality is changed.
I don't find any documentation stating that this will be changed.

Comment: The behavior that you're seeing is by design. New windows are opened with Edge if it is the same domain in order to support using cookies to pass data to the window. Outlook does not support opening multiple dialogs at a time. If this is functionality you would like, please add a request to our [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins).

Comment: While the dialog is the recommended approach as previously mentioned, if you just want actual multiple browser windows to open, have you considered window.open as an alternative?